# Timer job vs. site workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, timer-jobs

When doing a comparison between the following approaches, which one would you choose for creating a daily recurring task?

1. Timer job (classic)
2. Site workflow + web service (custom code)
3. Site workflow + code activity (more scalable)

Is there any upper limitation related to the number of timer jobs in s SP farm?

Trying to think about it from a scaling perspective, moving away all unnecessary business logic from the SP farm or isolating it on the site collection level.

Answer (score 2):

Alex,

I think it's going to depend on when you need the recurring task to execute. If you're okay with it running on a timescale (e.g. hourly, daily, etc), you can use Timer jobs. If you need to be based on an activity (e.g. list item updates), then you'll need go with a workflow or event receiver.

For a daily recurring task, you can go with a single Timer Job. It would make the most sense to encapsulate everything into one Timer Job if those tasks can all be executed at the same time. You will need to remember to reset the Timer Service when redeploying the solution.

You can read more about the limitations of each below.

[Difference between SharePoint WorkFlow, Event Receivers and Timer Job](http://www.dotnetplace.com/post/Difference-between-SharePoint-WorkFlow-Event-Receivers-and-Timer-Job.aspx)

Jim

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've added a little bit more detail to the description

Comment: updated answer.